# Can you store artifacts from a Release plan in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Release plan in Visual Studio Team Services Online that runs a small UI test (using Selenium) after web app deployment to ensure the app is functioning correctly.

I would like to store screenshots from this Release as artifacts so that they are accessible once the release completes (mainly in case the tests fail).

Is this possible using VSTS?

I've tried using the Copy Publish Artifact task as part of my Release plan but that just produces a few errors like `System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'StagingFolder' because it is null.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "##vso[task.uploadfile]" command to do this.

> **View and download attachments associated with releases**
>
> Would you like to upload additional logs or diagnostics or images when
>   running tasks in a release? This feature enables users to upload
>   additional files during deployments. To upload a new file, use the
>   following agent command in your script:
>
> Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]"
>
> The file is then available as part of the release logs. When you
>   download all the logs associated with the release, you will be able to
>   retrieve this file as well.

Comment: Thanks, the exact syntax was 
`Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadfile]local_file_path.ext"` (where local_file_path.ext is the file to upload)

Comment: A full list of the commands can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: I'm still not clear what I need to do here. Where do I save the file during release so that ##vso[task.uploadfile] can see if? Or does it not matter, can I save it anywhere?

Comment: Also, if the screen shots are named in the test (and there could be lots of them). How do I execute the command Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]" outside of the test task and get the names of the files which need to be included?